# How to replace a character in a text in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a pandas dataframe X_test that contains one column "review".
I want to check reviews and replace two characters as below:
O ==> 0 and b ==> 6
The replace method replaces just one character.
Any idea, please?

Comment: provide reproducible data./code and show us your desired output

Comment: `df['colname'] = df['colname'].apply(lambda s: s.replace(": O", '0').replace('b', '6'))`

Comment: How many characters do you have to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
X_test['column_name'] = X_test['column_name'].str.replace('O', '0')
X_test['column_name'] = X_test['column_name'].str.replace('b', '6')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
X_test["column"] = X_test["column"].replace({"O": "0", "b": "6"}, regex=True)
```